# Error. No provider for _SlickCarouselComponent found in NodeInjector. Angular 17

Tags: html, angular, angular-directive

I have `Angular: 17.2.0` application. I want use `ngx-slick-carousel: ^17.0.0`, I have already download all dependencies for this library, I follow to instruction, but I still have issue.

[image]

This error appears when I use `ngxSlickItem` directive in parent component.

Child component code (app-carousel-section):

```
<ngx-slick-carousel #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="carouselConfig">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ngx-slick-carousel>
```

Parent component code:

```
<app-carousel-section>
  <app-product-card ngxSlickItem [countActiveStars]="3"></app-product-card> <!-- The error appears when I add directive here -->
  <app-product-card [countActiveStars]="3"></app-product-card> <!-- Works, but slider doesnt see it -->
</app-carousel-section>
```

UPD: StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uiv5ea?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

Comment: I am not familiar with that library specifically, but do you know if it uses standalone components? If so, you need to import the component class in your `imports` array. If not, you need to add the module that component is declared in to your `imports` array. If your app is using standalone components, it would go in the component `imports`, if you are using modules, then it would go there.

Comment: @Geo242, Yes, I use standalone components. I have already imported all required modules, but the issue still persists

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz that replicates the issue?

Comment: @Geo242 pinned it into `UPD` ticket

Comment: Thank you for posting that. The main problem is that you haven't set up your project according to the directions here: https://github.com/leo6104/ngx-slick-carousel. You haven't installed the required libraries or adding the js or css includes into your angular.json. After you fix that, I think you are still going to have a problem with how you are expecting ng-content to work with the slide directive. Likely, the directive needs to be used as a direct child of the carousel component.